# mongodb timeout when debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mocha.js

I am debugging a nodejs test case with mocha and keep hitting this error as I debug with Chrome Dev Tools:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out]
```

I am using different test and development databases configured here:

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if(env === 'development') {
  process.env.PORT = 3000;
  process.env.MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp';
} else if (env === 'test') {
  process.env.PORT = 3000;
  process.env.MONGODB_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoAppTest';
}
```

How can I get past that timeout so I can debug without hitting this error?

Comment: you need to have mongodb running on your `localhost`

Comment: I have it running on `localhost`, ran `mongod` as well.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "debug with Chrome Dev Tools"? Isn't this a node app?

Comment: It is, i debug the nodejs app using Chrome Dev Tools - a debugger. The problem arises the app hits a breakpoint I set and pauses, causing the database to timeout

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the mognodb service locally in order to connect your application.
Run `mongod` command in terminal then restart your application.

Comment: I am! The db is working fine the problem is with tis timeout that gets triggered when i start debugging

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue and could go past it by disabling the break points at the start of debugger (in VS Code) and later again enabling them to continue with the debugging. The problem occurs only when RAM usage is high.

Edit: We could overcome this issue by using {useUnifiedTopology: true} as options to mongo client connection.